# How to configure IPVS loopback address with netplan in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, netplan

Previously, I configured IPVS loopback addresses in `/etc/network/interfaces`like this:

```
auto lo:0
iface lo:0 inet static
  address 12.34.56.78
  netmask 255.255.255.255
  pre-up sysctl -q -p
```

On 18.04, I tried adding this section to the netplan config:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    lo:
      addresses:
      - 12.34.56.78/32
```

And then ran `netplan apply`. systemd-networkd logs the following:

```
May 18 10:01:55 [...] systemd-networkd[3820]: lo: Adding address: 12.34.56.78/32 (valid forever)
May 18 10:01:55 [...] systemd-networkd[3820]: lo: Adding address: 127.0.0.1/8 (valid forever)
May 18 10:01:55 [...] systemd-networkd[3820]: rtnl: received address with invalid family 129, ignoring
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect (`ifconfig` doesn't list `lo:0`). Not sure what the invalid family 129 refers to. The actual address (it's not 12.34.56.78 :-) ) works fine when I manually use ifconfig to set it up.

I also tried using `lo:0` as the YAML key name, but then I get this error:

```
May 18 10:00:06 [...] systemd-networkd[3736]: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-lo:0.network:2: Interface name is not valid or too long, ignoring assignment: (null)
```

Looks like systemd-networkd doesn't like `lo:0` as an interface name. Any suggestions?

Comment: See my answer in this post, I think that is what you are looking for: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033403/how-to-setup-netplan-with-additional-loopback-addresses-but-mainly-use-networkma/1033864#1033864

Comment: @MikaelSchultz This seems very close to I want to do (lo:0 instead of lo:1). I tried explicitly specifying `renderer` and `match`, but that didn't seem to have any effect. Also FYI -- I updated the question with some more info from the logs. I wonder what I'm missing.

Comment: Turns out that my netplan config was actually working, but `ifconfig` could not display the additional loopback address assigned to `lo`. Problem solved :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the netplan configuration *did* assign the additional loopback address to lo, but `ifconfig` couldn't display it, which was misleading me. When I manually ran `ifconfig lo:0 12.34.56.78 netmask 255.255.255.255` it displayed `lo:0` just fine. But netplan assigned the address to `lo`, not `lo:0`. Running `ip addr` revealed the additional IP address on `lo`.

Upon further reading, I found that `ifconfig` (net-tools) has long been deprecated in favor of `ip` (iproute): https://serverfault.com/questions/633087/where-is-the-statement-of-deprecation-of-ifconfig-on-linux