# Giving loopback device another IP in EC2 user_data.sh?

Tags: networking, server, amazon-ec2

On an AWS EC2 instance, I would like to configure my loopback device with another IP, e.g. 10.0.0.100/32. The configuration would need to happen in the user_data.sh script, so is there a simple command for configuring a persistent configuration? I can of course just output a configuration file for the interface and run `netplan apply`, but I'm assuming there's some "correct" one-liner way of doing this with `netplan set`. This would be on an Ubuntu 22.04 AMI.

Comment: What would this change achieve? Some programs do not check which IP range has been set as loopback and assume it's 127.0.0.0/8. This would make you reconfigure (and some of them are not reconfigurable) every single loopback IP that was hard-coded.

Comment: Does it matter what it achieves? It's for IPIP tunneling for an eBPF program.

Comment: I'm also asking to make that IP an *additional* IP for the device not the only one.

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/a/1037876/1684306