# Wifi Problem After Setting Static IP in Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, static-ip, netplan

I set a static IP by following the instructions on https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/netplan-how-to-configure-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-18-04-using-netplan.html

At first, it worked. However, when I rebooted my laptop, Wifi didn't work anymore. The corresponding information are the following:

networkctl status -a

```
 1: lo
   Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Network File: n/a
        Type: loopback
       State: carrier (unmanaged)
     Address: 127.0.0.1
              ::1

● 2: enp2s0
   Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Network File: n/a
        Type: ether
       State: routable (unmanaged)
        Path: pci-0000:02:00.0
      Driver: r8169
      Vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Model: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
  HW Address: ... (ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.)
     Address: 10.5.150.56
              ...
     Gateway: 10.5.148.1 (Cisco Systems, Inc)

● 3: wlp3s0
   Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
Network File: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-wlp3s0.network
        Type: wlan
       State: off (configuring)
        Path: pci-0000:03:00.0
      Driver: rtl8723be
      Vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Model: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
  HW Address: 30:52:cb:ee:5c:c2 (Liteon Technology Corporation)
         DNS: 8.8.8.8
              8.8.4.4
```

/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
    dhcp4: no
    addresses: [192.168.43.131/24]
    gateway4: 192.168.1.1
    nameservers:
    addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
    access-points:
      F3-:
        password: ...
```

ifconfig -a

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.5.150.56  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 10.5.151.255
    inet6 ...  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether ...  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 13169  bytes 9405575 (9.4 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 7706  bytes 1033540 (1.0 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 1251  bytes 164695 (164.6 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1251  bytes 164695 (164.6 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether ...  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So, what can be the problem? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with assigning a static IP address to my WiFi interface rendered with networkd using Netplan. For me the main factor was that I had set the wrong password. Make sure that the access point exists, along with the correctly stated password. I blindly defined a no-existing access point before rebooting the system that set a static IP address when rendered with networkd believing it didn't matter. After the reboot, the WiFi no longer worked.

I'm not sure whether or not this is a bug, but trying to assign a static IP address for the WiFi interface rendered with NetworkManager did not apply my static IP address to my interface, even when viewed and defined visibly in the NetworkManager GUI (current bug report has been [created](https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1905465)). I relied on netplan YAML configuration rendered with networkd with proper credentials to avoid this problem. This worked as intended, but my system relied on a USB dongle for direct Ethernet connection as a backup network interface. After my Netplan settings were applied, I could not have any contact with my Ethernet interface connection. By default, NetworkManager is the default service for Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop, which manages network interfaces normally through the GUI. From my Netplan configuration, I explicitly stated configurations for my WiFi interface, but networkd did not automatically assign settings for new interfaces when detected on the system. I created a YAML configuration adapted from this SO [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1033864/1151435) to set all interfaces first with NetworkManager and then specified my WiFi interface to render with networkd for the static address assignment:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
    renderer: networkd
    wlp1s0:
      addresses: [192.168.1.231/24]
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1]
      access-points:
        accesspointename:
          password: passwordgoeshere
```

After a reboot I had an established connection with my static WiFi interface and ethernet interface was functioning as intended.

In case you would rather not reboot the entire system, and/or if the intended access point to connect to is different than what is already connected via NetworkManager or nmcli you can run the following commands in order to restart the services after applying netplan:

```
sudo netplan apply; sudo systemctl daemon-reload; sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager; sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service; sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: I think this is because of a misconfiguration. Ip of enp2s0 is 10.5.150.56 but gateway is from a  different segment. Enes should post output from 'ip address' and 'ip route'.

Answer (score 0):

First, the gateway address 192.168.1.1 is not in the same subnet with 192.168.43.131/24. One of the two is incorrect.

Second, netplan is very specific as to format, convention, indentation, spacing, etc. You can check an example here:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/netplan.io/examples/wireless.yaml
```

I suggest that you revise your yaml file to:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.43.131/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.43.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      access-points:
        "F3-":
          password: "..."
```

NOTE: Is F3- really the name of your network as the yaml file in your question suggests? Or is it F3 or some other? Substitute your details above.

Next, apply the changes:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Any improvement?

Comment: F3 is the name of the network. Networkctl state turned to "no-carrier" but wifi still doesn't work.

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep -e wlp -e net` May I assume that Network Manager is not installed and running here?

Comment: If the name of your network is F3 then this config looks incorrect since it lists F3-