# Share your Netplan configuration!

Tags: server, maas, openstack, cloud, netplan

This is Lukas Märdian a Netplan developer for Canonical. We are currently looking for ways to improve the Netplan YAML configuration schema [0]. Therefore, we would love to see the configuration files you use in your production environments and kindly ask you to share those in this post or by pasting them via https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ and sharing the link with us here.

We are especially interested if your setup is extra complex or special in any other way, so we can see and think about how to improve the schema for your use case to make Netplan configs easier to read and understand!

Please also let us know if you have any specific Netplan schema changes in mind, which would make your life easier! E.g. combining “gateway4:” and “gateway6:” into a single “gateway:” setting.

Please let us know what you think and share your crazy configs!

[0] https://netplan.io/reference

Comment: Do you want 'em if they're just bare bones? I suspect not, but [here you go](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/jqvrczRhkK/). I've not yet played with it, but it's on my list of things to learn. I have two distinct DSL lines, each on their own phone number, and plan to merge them. I just haven't gotten there yet. Of course, I've been saying I'll do this for years... Also, you may get more eyes on this by posting [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions) and [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/index.php) or maybe even [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replied to a previous SO [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061131/wifi-problem-after-setting-static-ip-in-ubuntu-18-04-01-lts/1296426#1296426) on statically assigning an IP address to a WiFi interface and allowing a mix between NetworkManager and networkd to provide Ethernet connectivity:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
    renderer: networkd
    wlp1s0:
      addresses: [192.168.1.231/24]
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1]
      access-points:
        accesspointename:
          password: passwordgoeshere
```