# Is it possible to set static IP on only for specific network, but use DHCP everywhere else?

Tags: networking, netplan, static-ip

I'm asking in cases for laptops when I want to connect to the internet using wired setup.  Would it be possible to apply my Netplan settings at one network only (i.e. my home), and have the default everywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Use NetworkManager for this.

Settings --> Network. Create two new Wired profiles (or just one new if you already have one)

- One is your not-home profile using DHCP.
- The other is your Home profile using Static IP.
- You can create other profiles, if you wish.

Switch between the profiles using the normal NetworkManager controls on your desktop or using nmcli (shell). It's possible --but more complicated-- to write a NetworkManager.Dispatcher script to detect whether you are on you home network and automatically select the correct profile.

If you decide to follow this path, migrate your Netplan settings into your NetworkManager profile. It won't happen automatically. Netplan should be reduced to the original stub, specifying NM at the network manager.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario sounds similar to a previous [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1296426/1151435) I replied to before. In my reply, using netplan I established a static IP address to an WiFi interface using a mix between NetworkManager and networkd. My system that utilizes this netplan configuration relies on a USB dongle for any Ethernet connection. This config sets a static IP address and automatically establishes an address to my connected Ethernet by NetworkManager. In case the provided link does not work properly below is an example YAML configuration:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
    renderer: networkd
    wlp1s0:
      addresses: [192.168.1.231/24]
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1]
      access-points:
        accesspointename:
          password: passwordgoeshere
```